# Creating a wrapper web part to host a user control in MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

i am trying to set up a wrapper for a user control to be used in Moss 2007 but there is a problem that I can see my user control hosted in the web part but the cs file is not being executed so all the functions and activities in the page_load and other functions is being ignored. I have followed this article.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/1126/

Can someone please suggest what should be done as it is such a simple task and it has wasted a lot of time on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why you are creating the wrapper yourself ? I'm asking this because there already is a great solution for this: the SmartPart by Jan Tielens.

http://smartpart.codeplex.com/

Comment: ya i know that. in fact i used the smartpart earlier but for some reason the client wants me not to use the smart part :(

Comment: last time i looked at smartpart it wasn't the safest of ways to implement functionality: requires too many permissions

Answer (score 0):

Did you set AutoEventWireup="true" in the ASCX file? If yes try to move your code CreateChildControls or Render to see whether your code is executed at all...

Answer (score 0):

I get this sometimes when I forget to adequately put the right namespaces in place. 
Your project needs to be signed and all ASCX files need to have the full namespace reference in:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="SampleWebPart.SampleWebUserControl, SampleWebPart,
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9f4da00116c38ec5" %>
```

Note the publickeytoken, you need your own value in there.